# Answer VoIP call on bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, headset

**Overview**

I'm currently working on an android app that supports VoIP calls (using [webrtc](https://webrtc.org)). Everything's working perfectly, but now I'm trying to add support for bluetooth headsets. I want the calls to be answered/hangup automatically (without the user touching the device's screen) if:

1. The user has a bluetooth headset connected to his device
2. The Answer/Hangup button was pressed

**Problem**

I'm still struggling to make this work. I've read all related stack overflow questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630886/accepting-a-call-via-bluetooth-headset-voip) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399672/accepting-a-call-via-bluetooth-headset)), but still no luck.
What I've tried:

1. Obtain the bluetooth profile proxy using `bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)`.
2. On the service listener (a `BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener`) check if the obtained `BluetoothHeadset` has a connected bluetooth device. If true, register a `BroadcastReceiver` with an `IntentFilter` that has the actions `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON`, `android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED` and `android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` and call `audioManager.startBluetoothSco()`.

I'm only receiving broadcasts for the `android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED` action. What's wrong with my approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not developed VoIP apps, so I am not sure about correct sequence of events and control calls in this case. Not sure that this can help, just some notes from Bluetooth point of view. Intents `BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` (`android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED`) are about `BluetoothHeadset`'s RFCOMM connection, it is kept alive if Handsfree/Headset profile is enabled for specific Handsfree unit and Handsfree unit is in use. You need these intents to detect if you need to look after BluetoothHeadset state or not, so you will not receive them during calls.
You can also register a receiver for `BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED` intents (`android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED`). In BluetoothHeadset source and accordingly in Android documentation it described as "Audio Connection state of the A2DP profile", but this is wrong. This is state of Handsfree/Headset physical audio SCO connection. This connection is active during voice calls, Bluetooth voice recognition and ringing (if In Band Ringing feature is supported and enabled). I do not remember how BluetoothHeadset audio state concerns AudioManager's SCO state.